# SVG clipping two sides of ellipse BUG

Tags: html, svg

I've created an svg and an ellipse inside it using the code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     version="1.1" 
     type="svgObj" 
     style="display: inline; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" 
     id="svg_5" 
     preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <ellipse type="svgShpObj" id="shape_2" cx="59px" cy="33px" rx="57px" ry="31px"
           fill="#A5A85A" stroke-width="10" stroke="#F5821F"
           stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="0.39215686274509803"/>
</svg>
```

paste it to http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_myfirst and check the problem that it clips left and top sides of the ellipse. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "clipped" parts of the SVG are simply outside of the viewport.

There are several ways to "fix" this.

You can reposition the ellipse (MDN docu [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/cy) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/cx)) by changing the respective coordinates to

```
 cx="70px" cy="40px"
```

Or you can explicitly set a viewBox ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)), that includes the whole ellipse, by adding, e.g.,

```
 viewBox="-10 -10 300 300"
```

to the `<svg>` element itself.